# Find a row in a table if the value is known in R

Tags: r, rows

I am analyzing a table of thousands of genes in **R**. Every gene is a row and has corresponding mRNA expression values. Within these values, I was asked to find the max expression values out of all the entries, which I did using the `max()` function. It returned the maximum expression value, but not the corresponding row (gene name). **Does anyone know how to find an unknown row for a known value in a table?**

Comment: `which.max` gives the index of the maximum value.

Comment: Also try `which.max(dataset==max(dataset), arr.ind=TRUE)`

Comment: -1. Please provide `head(your.table)`. This will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

To find the location of the maximum value, you can use the `which.max()` function.

More generally, if you want to get the location of an element that meets some criteria, you can use the `extract` operator `[` and perform an equality test. e.g. for data.frame `dat`:

```
which(dat == max(dat), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

This will return the array index in which the maximum value resides. You can change the condition to just about anything, with the same effect.

For more info on subsetting data using `extract`, refer to the help files `?'['`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can change the condition so long as it always produces a logical result. First argument must always be logical.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? There's probably a more elegant way to do this.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(1,1,1,6,2))
which.max(apply(df, 1, max))
```

It calculates max by row and then locates the row with the overall maximum. Depending on how many columns versus row you have, it might be faster to locate the column containing the maximum first and then finding the corresponding row:

```
match(max(df), df[, which.max(apply(df, 2, max))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an example:

```
> ddf = structure(list(ex1 = c(10L, 35L, 18L), ex2 = c(20L, 20L, 42L), 
    ex3 = c(30L, 15L, 25L)), .Names = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("abcd", 
"defg", "ijkl"))

> ddf
     ex1 ex2 ex3
abcd  10  20  30
defg  35  20  15
ijkl  18  42  25
```

If max of columns is to be found:

```
> data.frame(maxrow=rownames(ddf)[apply(ddf, 2, which.max)], maxval=apply(ddf, 2, max))
    maxrow maxval
ex1   defg     35
ex2   ijkl     42
ex3   abcd     30
```

or:

```
> t(data.frame(maxrow=rownames(ddf)[apply(ddf, 2, which.max)], maxval=apply(ddf, 2, max)))
       ex1    ex2    ex3   
maxrow "defg" "ijkl" "abcd"
maxval "35"   "42"   "30"
```

If max of rows is to be found:

```
> idx = apply(ddf, 1, which.max)
> outdf = data.frame(gene=rownames(ddf), maxcol=colnames(ddf)[idx], maxval=apply(ddf, 1, max))
> rownames(outdf) = 1:nrow(ddf)
> outdf
  gene maxcol maxval
1 abcd    ex3     30
2 defg    ex1     35
3 ijkl    ex2     42
```

or:

```
> data.frame(maxcol=colnames(ddf)[apply(ddf, 1, which.max)], maxval=apply(ddf, 1, max))
     maxcol maxval
abcd    ex3     30
defg    ex1     35
ijkl    ex2     42
```